# New Xively server error (503) on production system

Tags: xively, server-error

I have an Arduino which has been successfully sending data to Pachube, then Cosm, now Xively for years. 
I have a page to monitor the data (www.iphealth.info) which displays png images using this code for about 8 different data feeds:
img src="https://api.xively.com/v2/feeds/63142/datastreams/2896DB79300EC.png?width=800&height=212&c=F53527&duration=1day&title=Hot%20Tub&b=true&g=true&scale=auto&timezone=-8"

This has been working successfully for literally years until yesterday which I am getting a "Xively Server Error" image instead of my data image for all of the data feeds.
I have checked the Xively site and my data is still being successfully loaded into the site. However, I can't get any data out of the site.
I have changed nothing. I can see the GET requests and all it says is error 503.
Has Xively changed something?

Answer (score 1):

Well... as soon as I posted about this problem it started working again. Even thought the Xively dashboard was reporting that it was receiving the data during that time, it is not there for a 36 hour period. Now it is working just fine but I have this 36 hour gap in my data (all 7 channels from two different devices).
It doesn't look like there's any way to inquire directly with Xively about this outage... I guess that's what you get for a free service.

Comment: If you have answered your own question, can you mark it as answered (i.e. accept your own answer), in order to take it off the Unanswered list? Thanks.